# Is it possible to specify function overrides in JSDoc?

Tags: webstorm, jsdoc

An example of what I'm looking to document would be the following:

```
/**
 * @return {boolean}
 */
Contains(rectangle_or_x, y, tolerance) {
    if (rectangle_or_x instanceof Rectangle) { return ((rectangle_or_x.X >= this._x) && (rectangle_or_x.Y >= this._y) && (rectangle_or_x.Right <= this._right) && (rectangle_or_x.Bottom <= this._bottom)); }
    if ((tolerance === undefined) || (tolerance === null) || (!Rectangle._isNumeric(tolerance))) {
        if ((rectangle_or_x < this._x) || (y < this._y) || (rectangle_or_x > this._right) || (y > this._bottom)) { return (false); }
    } else if (((rectangle_or_x + tolerance) < this._x) || ((y + tolerance) < this._y) || ((rectangle_or_x - tolerance) > this._right) || ((y - tolerance) > this._bottom)) { return (false); }
    return (true);
}
```

Within this there are 3 possible calls, one of which could just be ignored as it is based around the optional `tolerance` argument, but the base two overlap in an exclusive manner:

```
Contains(Rectangle rectangle_or_x)
Contains(Number rectangle_or_x, Number y[, Number tolerance])
```

Given the differing types (I know JavaScript is un-typed, but as far as the example is concerned there are definitive types involved) is it possible to create separate sets of `@param` values with JSDoc (mainly for intellisense in WebStorm, but theoretically also for documentation down the line.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to specify exclusive sets of JSDocs.

You can try something like:

```
/**
 * @param {Rectangle|Number} rectangle_or_x
 * @param {Number=} y
 * @param {Number=} tolerance
 * @return {boolean}
 */
Contains(rectangle_or_x, y, tolerance) {}
```